# Oracle field for save the dollar

Tags: database, oracle10g

I have to save the dollar into the table which datatype should i use.  I know Number datatype but i want to store like `25,0000` for that which datatype should i use either `number or varchar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be a poor choice to do this (as eventually someone would save a corrupt string to that column and break your code).

I would have the table as a `number` and just have a view over the top of it that concatenates the $ to the number if needed (`select '$'||your_col, ...`). if you need  multiple currencies, then you'd best be served with a currency column that contains the currency code like `USD`.

Comment: I am using hibernate pojo for save and retieve how can i use to_char

Answer (score 1):

Use number and then use TO_CHAR and the correct format mask (NLS dependent)

```
create table curr_test (col number);
insert into curr_test (col) values (15.25);
select to_char(col, 'L00D00') from curr_test;
```

Link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#NLSPG221